# Solve the equation $22\log(92x+40.66)=38.9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The equation
$$22\log(92x+40.66)=38.9$$

steps so far

$$\log(92x+40.66)=\frac{38.9}{22}$$

to eliminate log, do I have to apply the opposite of log? Not sure what that is.

Comment: Exponentiation is the oppisite of log

Comment: @Amr so I'm headed in the right direction, with doing the opposite?

Comment: Yes, exponentiate both sides.  Where did the minus sign in front of $\log$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$22\log(92x+40.66)=38.9\Longrightarrow \log(92x+40.66)=\frac{38.9}{22}\Longrightarrow$$

$$92x+40.66=e^{\frac{38.9}{2}}\Longrightarrow \,\,\ldots$$

If by $\,\log\,$ you mean logarithm in base $\,10\,$ just change $\,e\,$ for $\,10\,$

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$\log_{b}u=v \iff b^v=u.$$

Apply this fact. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might have heard that 
$$
b^{\log_b(x)} = x.
$$
Most people that I am aware of just write $\log$ when they mean $\log_{10}$. So that would mean that 
$$
10^{\log(x)} = x.
$$ 
Now you have the equation 
$$
\log(92x+40.66)=\frac{38.9}{22}
$$
and to get rid of the $\log$ you can 
$$
10^{\log(92x+40.66)}=10^{\frac{38.9}{22}}.
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
92x + 40.66 = 10^{\frac{38.9}{22}}
$$
and this is just a linear equation that you probably know how to solve (on both sides: subtract $40.66$ and then divide by $92$).